# Call custom function using events and observer

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I need to call our own custom function after save, delete, add products in Magento. I need to call in the separate file that is located in Magento root folder.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

Magento has events for every controller action, both before and after executing. In your case you'll want to use `catalog_product_delete_after` and `catalog_product_save_after`.

I'm not really sure what you mean by `add` tho, is that for a new product? In that case you can observer `...save` as well.

It would look something like this in your `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <module]>
             <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
        </[module]>
    </models>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
          <[namespace]_[module]_save_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>save</method>
          </[namespace]_[module]_save_observer>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_save_after>
      <catalog_product_save_delete>
        <observers>
          <[namespace]_[module]_delete_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>delete</method>
          </[namespace]_[module]_delete_observer>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_save_delete>     
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

For more info on observers please check [this wikipage](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: .Can we do this in separate file at magento folder without making any module

Comment: You might be able to add it to the etc/global.xml, since all XMLs are concatenated but I would advise you to make an extension. It's not that much work and a whole lot cleaner

Comment: Thanks a lot.You saved a lot of time .Thank you very much .I will do it by making a small extension

Comment: Can you add me on my personal gmail id so that i will be in contact you for my help?

Comment: I normally don't give out my contact details. If you have a question you can always post it on this forum, I'm here pretty much all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the default events for these action `catalog_product_save_after` (and others), and create an observer that has some methods that act as wrappers for your custom functions. Something like:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getBaseDir().'your_functions.php';
class Company_Module_Model_Observer{
    public function catalog_product_save_after($observer){
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        yourFunction($product);//call function from your external file
    }
   //all other methods here
}
```

Even if this should work, I don't approve of this kind of code. You should keep the Magento standards and have your functions inside an observer.

Comment: Thanks for help.Am I need to make a module or I can call observer directly in file that is at magento root folder.

Comment: @deepu. If you take this approach then you need to create a new module. But before doing so, take a look at the answer provided by SanderMangel. it has more code in it that should help you.

Comment: ok thanks.I will do it by making a new module